# Reset all the state of child and parent class by a button in the parent class - React native

Tags: react-native

I've a parent class with its child classes. When the child class is clicked, its id is passed to parent class and the bg color of the child is changed.
I want to reset all the state and bgColor of child class by clicking the button in the parent class. How can I achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Parent class:

```
getSelectedChilds = (id) => {
    const items = this.state.selectedIds.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        this.setState({
            selectedIds: [...items]
        });
}

render() {
    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Child getSelectedChilds={this.getSelectedChilds} item={item} />}
            />
            <Button
                onPress={() => {
                        // how to reset all the states (parent & child) by clicking this button?
                }}
                title="Submit"
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Child class

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectChild: false
        }
    }
    
    selectedChild = (id) => {
        this.setState({
            selectChild: !this.state.selectChild
        });
        this.props.getSelectedChilds(id);
    }
    
    render() {
        const { item } = this.props;
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        activeOpacity={0.8}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.selectedChild(item.id);
                        }}>
                        <View style={[{ backgroundColor: this.state.selectChild ? 'red' : 'transparent' }]}>
                            
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                            </View>
                            
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )
    }
}
```

What I did so far:
I used refs to access the function of child. It works but the state of child classes can not be changed, and hence bgColor is red all the time.

Parent class

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child = React.createRef();
}

resetAll = () => {
    this.setState({
        selectedIds: [...items]
    });
    this.child.current.reset(); // this is not working properly
}

render() {
    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Child ref={this.child} getSelectedChilds={this.getSelectedChilds} item={item} />}
            />
            <Button
                onPress={() => {
                        this.resetAll()
                }}
                title="Submit"
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Child class

```
reset = () => {
    alert('abc'); //the alert works but the line after this doesn't work and the bg color is unchanged.
    this.setState({
        selectChild: false
    });
}

render() {
    const { item } = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.8}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.selectedChild(item.id);
                    }}>
                    <View style={[{ backgroundColor: this.state.selectChild ? 'red' : 'transparent' }]}>
                        
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                        </View>
                        
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass a boolean in your child to tell him to reset its own state. Something like :

```
const resetAll = () => {
  this.setState({
    // ... whatever you want,
    resetChild: true
  });
}
```

And then

```
<Child shouldReset={this.state.resetChild} />
```

By cliking on your button, you will trigger a re-render in your child and this child will handle its own state.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get u, theres already selectChild state is all the child components, how to make them false through resetChild state?

Comment: I didn't see you were managing multiple child sorry, but the idea is still the same. In your Child component, you could have a useEffect triggered by a prop (With a dependency) that decide if you need to reset the background or not witha simple if statement. I tried to do a repro but for some reason basic things does not works and it's driving me crazy. I hope my explanation are clear tho ! Note that managing a child state through ref isn't a good idea I think, the child should manage its own state.

Comment: Hum also you're not using hooks haha (You should !), so I guess you will do the check in a componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method.